# RecycleView fling slow down to stop animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-recyclerview

I am trying to slow down and stop fling event released by `RecycleView`. This is a actual behavior [YT video](https://youtu.be/TLXAtvj9oDc)

- On long fling, collapsing is super fast, I'd love to slow it down
- On short fling there is no inertia after releasing the finger from the screen. It stops immediately.

Other other hand, when trying to expand view:

- On long fling it stops somewhere in the middle, no inertia as well - the collapsing long fling would be great here

I tried several velocity coefficients in overridden `fling` method:

```
@Override
public boolean fling(int velocityX, int velocityY) {
    if (velocityY > 0) {
        // Collapsing
        velocityY = (int) (0.5 * velocityY);
    } else {
        // Expanding
        velocityY = (int) (2.5 * velocityY);
    }
    return super.fling(velocityX, velocityY);
}
```

These are my latest values but could not see any difference in expanding after increasing value of negative velocity. When I lowered the number near to 0, fling was disabled.